# Visual Studio is prompting to install ASP.NET Web pages with Razor syntax 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I'm somewhat at a loss as what to do with my development environment. Anytime I open up a solution Visual Studio is prompting me to install "ASP.NET Web pages with Razor syntax 1.0".

If I ignore the prompt and continue into the solution the only thing that appears to not work is intellisense within razor views. Not the end of the world but it is starting to get annoying having this message appear when moving from solution to solution.

I have tried:

- installing the missing component via the web platform installer
- installing the missing component via the standalone installer
- Uninstalling and re-installing MVC3

Any suggestions on what I can try next?

[image: Visual Studio Prompt]

**EDIT:**

So, after uninstalling all tools related to visual studio and and visual studio sp1 I re-installed visual studio and service pack1. I went to install MVC3 and the installation failed.

From, there I cleared pretty much every temp file / directory on my machine and tried the web platform installer. Again, it failed.

From there, I tried installed the RTM of MVC3 and the installation was successful: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4211

After finally getting MVC3 installed I was able to install the tools update and I'm back up and running....good way to waste 4 hours of time....blah...

Comment: Simply issuing an "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" worked for me. It brought in MVC 4 and all is well.

Comment: Thanks for updating this with your solution. Installing the MVC 3 package worked for me too! http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any suggestions on what I can try next?

I would attempt a Visual Studio 2010 reinstall after uninstalling ASP.NET MVC 3 and WebPages. Then install ASP.NET MVC 3 from the standalone installer.

Comment: Thanks Darin, will give that a try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

you have to uninstall all visual studio components (from add remove programs in control panel), install Visual Studio 2010, install asp.net mvc3 (with WPI) before upgrade to SP1, and then install Visual 2010 SP1.

If you upgrade to SP1 without install MVC 3, you will never can install mvc 3 again :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could solve this without reinstalling my studio or something else.

In the web.config i had the following entry requiring version 0.1 of razor:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="webpages:Version" value="0.1.1.0" />
</appSettings
```

I changed it to:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
</appSettings
```

Next time I opened the Solution the Prompt was gone.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me! I made sure the version in my packages.config matched the one in web.config. Cheers